# How to print a char matrix in Java so that the columns are alligned?

Tags: java

I've been trying to print a char matrix consisting only of lowercase letters in java. At first I was defining a String out of the matrix entries and then using JOptionPane to print it, but apparently due to the different spacing of the letters, the columns were not alligned so it looks bad. The code was the following:

```
String wordSearch = ""; 
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){   
  for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    wordSearch = wordSearch + matrix[i][j] +"\t";    
  } 
wordSearch = wordSearch + "\n"; 
} 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wordSearch);
```

Then I attempted just printing the matrix using System.out as follows

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
      System.out.print(matrix[i][j] +"   ");
    }
  System.out.println();
  }
```

and the output looks perfect, the columns are well alligned.

So my question is how can I achieve the same result using JOptionPane or something similar? Why does the output look different when I print it in the console?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Did you setup your widget to use a *fixed-width font*? like Courier or something

Comment: You can choose HTML `<table>` tag with `swing` component.

Comment: You can use a `Formatter` to align fields

Comment: @RC. Dear RC, I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but I don't think I even know how to do that.

Comment: @fge I tried using String.format() but the output didn't come out right. It only looked good and well alligned when I tried the System.out.print() code.

Comment: What format specifier did you use? Something like `%-8d` works wonderfully for alignment... But as @RC. mentions, you should use a fixed width font anyway

Comment: @fge Dear fge, my knowledge is very limited since I'm just starting to learn all this stuff, but I tried using something like %1$2s.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 16));
final StringBuilder wordSearch = new StringBuilder(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
        wordSearch.append(matrix[i][j]).append('\t');    
    } 
    wordSearch.append('\n'); 
} 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wordSearch.toString());
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks a lot RC. I tried your code, but I'm getting the following error:
"cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Font"
Do you know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: You miss an import: `java.awt.Font`

Comment: Thanks a lot RC. Your code works now, but unfortunately I'm still getting the alignment problems in the columns.